# A weird Scrollview Warning... creating problems in building apk in Flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollview, shrinkwrap

I don't know why I am seeing this error in the flutter packages path with shrinkwrap problem... and every time I try generating or building an apk of my code, this error stops the compiler with the message below.

```
PS D:\Flutter_apps\splash_screen> flutter clean
Deleting 'build\'.
PS D:\Flutter_apps\splash_screen> flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with
"--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                           1.5s
Resolving dependencies...                                        3.0s
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

Compiler message:
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:670:10: Error: Duplicated parameter name 'shrinkWrap'.
    bool shrinkWrap = false,
         ^^^^^^^^^^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:663:17: Error: Other parameter named 'shrinkWrap'.
  ListView(bool shrinkWrap, {
                ^^^^^^^^^^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/about.dart:476:28: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
            child: ListView(
                           ^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:663:3: Error: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  ListView(bool shrinkWrap, {
  ^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dropdown.dart:191:34: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
                  child: ListView(
                                 ^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:663:3: Error: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  ListView(bool shrinkWrap, {
  ^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/stepper.dart:544:20: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
    return ListView(
                   ^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:663:3: Error: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  ListView(bool shrinkWrap, {
  ^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/stepper.dart:602:26: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
          child: ListView(
                         ^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:663:3: Error: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  ListView(bool shrinkWrap, {
  ^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/two_level_list.dart:282:20: Error: Too few positional arguments: 1 required, 0 given.
    return ListView(
                   ^
file:///D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/scroll_view.dart:663:3: Error: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  ListView(bool shrinkWrap, {
  ^
Compiler failed on D:\Flutter_apps\splash_screen\lib/main.dart
14.7s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I even tried `flutter clean` but it's not working.... and tried searching about it on google but couldn't find anything.

Comment: even tried flutter upgrade... not working

Comment: How about Deleting the Flutter SDK Folder & Downloading it Again.?

Comment: won't it create any problems with my existing working projects?

Comment: Not Exactly - you are just downloading the SDK again - Put it in the same folder as before. run - flutter_console.bat again present in flutter folder.

Comment: yes it worked thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-installing Flutter SDK solves the problem.